# EntityFramework - An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When running my asp.net mvc solution, I'm presented with this error.

`Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException:
(261,10) : error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 261:No mapping specified for properties File.ImageFile in Set Files.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
 Entity is type [MTECommerce.Models.File]`

What I am trying to do is attach a one to many relationship to my AspNetUsers.

I want to be able to link files to users.

These are the following changes I've made.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<File> Images { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Added a File.cs class

```
public class File 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFile ImageFile { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

EF Migration File

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Files",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    CreationDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ModifiedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ImagePath = c.String(),
                    User_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.User_Id)
            .Index(t => t.User_Id);
```

May I get some guidance as to where I may be going wrong.

Comment: ImageFile is not supported in Db... mark as [notmapped] or remove from entity

Comment: @Seabizkit thank you! That was exactly the issue.